# Populating listview from a different activity with items from a SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-activity

I have a class which extends ListActivity within I have all methods for managing database items: insertItems(), getItems(), showItems(), etc. Everything works great when I populate this list view with items from the database. What I want to do, is to populate in the same way an another ListView from another activity but when I am trying to pass the cursor to that activity I get NullPointer Exception. I try to put what is most representative.

```
public class FOO extends ListActivity{
//...
public static DBAdapter items;
@override
public void onCreate(){
   //...
   items = new DBAdapter(this);
   //...
}
public static Cursor getAllItems() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db = items.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.query(DBConstants.TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null, null, null);
   }
```

then, in the second activity I have:

```
public class BAR extends ListActivity{
//.....
public FOO foo = new FOO();
Cursor cursor;
 //...
public static DBAdapter items;
@override
public void onCreate(){
   //...
   items = new DBAdapter(this);
   foo.insertItems(//arguments);
   this.cursor = foo.getAllItems();
   this.startManagingCursor(this.cursor);
   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_list, cursor,     FROM, TO);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

What I get first is this error, where MainActivity = BAR

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(22923): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{your.pack.databasae/your.pack.databasae.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Could you include the instantiation of items? It looks as though it's a SQLiteOpenHelper which can't be instantiated without an instance of Context (say, an Activity) but you're returning it from a static method which won't have such an instance. My guess is it's items which is null.

Comment: Yes, you're right, DBAdapter is the class that extends  SQLiteOpenHelper. I have instantiated **items** at the same way in both classes, I don't know if is ok....

Comment: Okay I see now. What role does the instance of Foo play? Without seeing Foo.insertItems I'm going to guess that it operates on a separate, static instance of DBAdapter which is expected to be instantied in the onCreate method of Foo.
It would probably be better to instantiate and use DBAdapter within the lifecycle of each activity and definitely not as statics. And you shouldn't be instantiating other Activities at all.
I hope that's helpful. If not feel free to include the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public FOO foo = new FOO();`

You should never be creating activities like this, its up to the framework to construct activities as needed.  That said if you need to do it this way, make sure `items` and `db` are created in the constructor for FOO (typical code would have it get created in `onCreate()` which would lead to a NPE here).  Nothing in BAR ever calls FOO's onCreate so `items` and presumably `db` are both null.

Alternatively, try to refactor your code such that the database management code is available in a separate class accessible from both ListActivity classes.

Comment: Yes, you're right. `items` and `db` are created somewhere inside FOO,in `onCreate()`, not in the constructor, but I have also instantiated `items` in BAR. I have declared `new FOO()` just to be able to call `getAllItems`

Comment: Unfortunately getAllItems() has a reference to a null class member.  I really recommend getting the database code out of the activities to promote reuse. note that you'll get other errors if you call FOO's onCreate() from BAR...

Comment: I agree that you should never create an activity like this, I disagree with the caveat that follows "That said". You should never instantiate an activity directly from another activity, period. It is never necessary and cause any number of weird problems as you are bypassing the normal activity lifecycle management. If there is non-UI behavior that two activities need to share, that should be moved into a separate class as Chris and others have suggested.

Comment: Ok guys, let's see if I got it, you recommend me create a new class, `BAZ`,which is not an activity, where to put all that methods that work with database, including `getAllItems()`.Than, will it be safe to do: `public BAZ baz = new BAZ()` and then `baz.getAllItems()` in my ListActivities? What give me headaches, is where and how, to instantiate **items**, it's enough if I do it only in `BAZ`? One more advice please :D

Comment: OK, I have put in practice all of these and SUCCESS! I have created a new class that manage the database access, having a constructor where I initiate **items** with a new context, than I call it using `new BAZ(this)` in my ListActivity. Hope is a good practice. Thank you all for yours hints!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create two more classes:

- A database adapter class, in which you can handle database access
- A sub class of AsyncTask, which handles saving/loading data to/from your database. In this task you can also populate your listview with data.

Maybe also [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) would be nice solution for your

Comment: This solution could be nice, but since I'm a novice,presumably I will get lock. But I will analyse fragments since seems to be very useful,and  also AsyncTask and I will try to understand how it works. :D thanks